# Disable @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity for testing

Tags: spring, security

I read the previous post regarding a solution for disabling @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity, but it doesn't work for me. Basically, I need to enable/disable my @PreAuthorize annotations on startup for testing purposes. Here is my relevant code:

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity
public class OpenAMMethodSecurityConfig extends GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration {

...
    @Value("${security.enabled}")
    private boolean enabled;
...

    protected MethodSecurityMetadataSource customMethodSecurityMetadataSource() {
        return enabled ? new SecuredAnnotationSecurityMetadataSource() : null;
    }
```

While the code will disable method security, it won't reenable it if the "enabled" flag is set to true and unless the annotation contains ...(prePostEnabled = true). In researching the code I think the prePostEnabled ever gets set to true as a result of executing customMethodSecurityMetadataSource().

Please advise...

Answer (score 3):

You can create a test configuration that will override `MethodSecurityMetadataSource` and effectively prevent security methods to be invoked. This will allow you to keep the logic only in the test part of the app without polluting the main code with test logic. Later, you just put `@ActiveProfiles("security-light")` on the respective spring boot tests.

```
@Configuration
@Profile("security-light")
public class SecurityLightConfiguration {

    @Bean
    @Primary
    MethodSecurityMetadataSource doTheMagic() {
        return new DelegatingMethodSecurityMetadataSource(Collections.emptyList());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a test property to disable the settings based on what you have...

```
@TestPropertySource(properties = "security.enabled:false")
```